# Search bulk images using keyword and save the links to Excel file

Tags: python, python-3.x, browser-automation

I'm working on a ecommerce project. I need to import 4k+ products. I'm really tired to search images manually, so I need a python script for the automation. I have a product names, I just need save the image links to the excel file as per the keywords respectively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's not how SO work, this isn't a free coding service.
Show what you tried, and point your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.